# PhpStorm - ignore .gitignore file

Tags: git, intellij-idea, phpstorm, gitignore

In PhpStorm after I did `npm install`, a couple of files appeared as unversioned. I added them to `.gitignore` as I don't want to work with them.

But now I have under default changelist the `.gitignore` file and also `package-lock.json`.

I am not able to remove them from there neither to ignore them.

I have found one solution, to mark those files as a plain text, they will be probably ignored then, however not sure if this is the best solution...

Comment: `.gitignore` is normal to be in your staging area, since you want to keep track of it. `package-lock.json` might have been tracked before you have excluded it in the ignore file. Is that the case?

Comment: package-lock I did not exclude from anywhere, it just appeared there after npm install and I can't add it to gitignore. But maybe I will rollback both files, I don't want to deal with them each time I commit the default changelist files. I know I can create a new changelist and work there, but still, I don't want these files there. Or I'll just mark them as a plain text and they will be not tracked. I don't need to track them unless I will do another npm install

Comment: Files can be added to git automatically if you have set "Add silently" under Preferences | Version Control | Confirmation.

If filenames are green - click on them and then click "Rollback" it will remove them from Git, or run `git rm --cached <filename>`. and then add `package-lock.json` to .gitignore

Comment: For some reason after I rollback all, I was able to add to gitignore those files finally